# Building an xml string with the form elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm working in building an xml string with the element values in a HTML form with java script. I'm able to get all the values of the form and build an xml easily with the below code. But the problem is there are a few repeating groups which makes the process hard. Means that, the repeating groups are FIELD SETS and for example if there is a field set named xxxRepeatingGroup and yyyRepeatingGroup, the xml should be as follows.

```
<xxxRepeatingGroup>
<xxx>
all the element values inside the field set with the name of the element as tag name and the value in between the tags here
</xxx>
<xxx>
all the element values inside the next field set(the repeating thing with different values) here
</xxx>
</xxxRepeatingGroup>
<yyyRepeatingGroup>
    <yyy>
    all the element values inside the field set with the name of the element as tag name and the value in between the tags here
    </yyy>
    <yyy>
    all the element values inside the next field set(the repeating thing with different values) here
    </yyy>
    </yyyRepeatingGroup>
```

I'm not able to find a logic to add the `<xxxRepeatingGroup>`, `<yyyRepeatingGroup>`,  `<xxx>` and `<yyy>` tags and I will not be able to hard code these tags as I need to use the same method in all the places.

Below is my java script function:

```
function getElementnames() { 
var msg = "";

 for (j=0;j < document.forms.mf.elements.length;j++) { 
  if (document.forms.mf.elements[j].type != 'button' && document.forms.mf.elements[j].type != 'submit' && document.forms.mf.elements[j].type == undefined )
 {
msg +=  startElement(document.forms.mf.elements[j].name ) +  document.forms.mf.elements[j].value + endElement(document.forms.mf.elements[j].name ); 
}
}
alert(msg);
}

function startElement(startname) {

    var startname="<"+ startname +">";
    return startname;
    }

function endElement(endname) {

    var endname ="</"+ endname +">";
    return endname;
    }
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do this by adding the element which I require as the tag name with type hidden and place it where ever I need the repeating group tags.